# WinEdt to TexStudio - transition

Tags: errors, texstudio, winedt

I have some file which were created in WinEdt. However, when I try to open them in TexStudio, TexStudio returns a lot of errors...
I should be able to open these files without errors, right? Or some sintax changes? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the file encoding?

Comment: The editor should be irrelevant. But what kind of errors are you talking about? And do you get them when you *open* the file, or when you are trying to make a PDF?

Comment: Firstly, I am a novice!! I am using UTF-8, @Texnician! @Torbjørn T., I am having all types, seriously!

Comment: I cant past the whole code in here, because it is huge.. I know the files were created in WinEdt but, even when i run WinEdt, I have errors.. Since I am a novice, I am not sure if there are initial errors.. The author stated in his blog that it runs..

Comment: If the files show errors in winedt and Texstudio, they probably contain `tex` errors, but if you dont' show them, we cannot help you.

Comment: If you are novice, you could start commenting all text in you file, between `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`. This way you can test the preamble. If it doesn't show errors, try uncommenting some lines from the text. And ..., so on

Comment: Can I post a link with the files?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it.. I think I may be a little advance, since it is a fancy template.. I am using TexStudio. Do you think it is better to use Texmaker?

Comment: Whe don't know if you can, but you are allowed to ;) And no, definitely use TexStudio over Texmaker (basically TexStudio is an enhanced Texmaker).

Comment: In that case, can I open a chat window and post the files there, please?

Comment: No editor winedt, texstudio etc is responsible for the tex error messages they come from tex and it never makes any difference which editor a file was written in. If you get errors please show the full error message from `!` to `?` from the log file in a code section in the question so line breaks are preserved.